# Why is 'this' not updating to refer to a new object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, scope, this

I'm writing an online game which allows a user to progress from one puzzle to the next, and if the user makes mistakes, each puzzle has a start again button to allow the user to start just that puzzle from scratch. A simplified version of the code's structure is below:

```
function puzzle(generator) {

    this.init = function() {
        this.generator = generator;
        ...
        this.addListeners();
    }

    //fires when the puzzle is solved
    this.completed = function() {
       window.theSequence.next();
    }

    this.empty = function() {
        //get rid of all dom elements, all event listeners, and set all object properties to null;
    }

    this.addListeners = function() {
       $('#startOver').click(function() {
            window.thePuzzle.empty();
            window.thePuzzle.init();
       });
    }
    this.init();
}

function puzzleSequence(sequenceGenerator) {

    this.init = function() {
        //load the first puzzle
        window.thePuzzle = new puzzle({generating json});

    }

    this.next = function() {
        //destroy the last puzzle and create a new one
        window.thePuzzle.empty();
        window.thePuzzle = new puzzle({2nd generating json});
    } 

}

window.theSequence = new puzzleSequence({a sequence generator JSON});
```

The problem I have is that if the user has progressed to the second puzzle, if they click start over it loads the first puzzle rather than the second. After a bit of debugging I've worked out that 'this', when used in methods by the second puzzle, for some reason still holds a reference to the first puzzle, but 'window.thePuzzle' - which should be the same as this - correctly refers to the second puzzle.

Why is 'this' persisting in referrring to the first one?

Let me know if you need more code samples

Comment: Much of this answer depends on what is in "start over"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $('#startOver').click(this.empty);

You've taken the `empty` method and detached it from `this` to pass as a plain unbound function to jQuery. When it gets called back, it will have no reference to the original value of `this`. In fact, when a function is called unbound, `this` will refer to `window`, so you'll be scribbling what you think are properties onto the globals.

JavaScript doesn't bind methods in the same way as other languages. See eg. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544735/js-object-this-method-breaks-via-jquery#1544893) for an explanation of what it actually does. This confuses many people; personally I consider it one of JavaScript's worst flaws.

Comment: This is kinda what I'd expect it to be, but I've checked using console.log and 'this', in this specific context, somehow still refers to the old version of window.thePuzzle

Comment: There still isn't enough code to reproduce the problem, but my suspicion would be somewhere in the code you have elided you are using `window.thePuzzle` in code that is called by the `puzzle` constructor, such as `init` or `addListeners`. At that point, the `puzzleSequence` code that says `window.thePuzzle= new puzzle` won't have written the new object to `window.thePuzzle` yet — it can't, until the constructor has finished executing.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very good (and clear) description of exactly how the `this` reference is treated in different contexts over at [Quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html).