# Javascript HTTP Request Queue within object variable - initialization doesn't work

Tags: javascript, object, variables, queue, xmlhttprequest

I got the following Request Queue implementation from this blog:

http://dsgdev.wordpress.com/2006/10/28/building-a-javascript-http-request-queue/

and want to wrap it with a object variable. Unfortunately the variable initialization inside doesn't work.

Hope someone can help me with this stuff. Thanks in advance

```
var requestQueue = {
    inCall          : false,            // VARIABLE TO TRACK IF WE ARE CURRENTLY IN A CALL
    callToArray     : new Array(),      // QUEUE FOR CALLS
    returnToArray   : new Array(),      // QUEUE FOR FUNCTION TO EXECUTE WHEN CALL COMPLETE
    reqMethodArray  : new Array(),      // QUEUE FOR REQUEST METHOD

    createRequestObject : function(){
      var reqObj;
      var browser = navigator.appName;
      if(browser == "Microsoft Internet Explorer"){
        reqObj = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        isIE = true;
      }else{
        reqObj = new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
      return reqObj;
    },

    sendCall : function(whereTo, returnTo, reqMethod){
      // GET THE NEXT ARRAY ITEM AND REMOVE FROM THE ARRAY
      this.callToArray.push(whereTo);
      this.returnToArray.push(returnTo);

      if (reqMethod != "GET" || reqMethod != "POST") { reqMethod = "GET"; }
      this.reqMethodArray.push(reqMethod);
    },

    callQueue : function(){
      // CHECK THE QUEUE AND SEND THE NEXT CALL IN LINE
      if(!this.inCall && this.callToArray.length > 0){
        // DO WE HAVE ANYTHING IN THE QUEUE?
        if(this.callToArray.length > 0){
          // WE DO, SO GET THE FIRST ITEM IN THE CALL ARRAY AND REMOVE IT
          whereTo = this.callToArray.shift();
          returnTo = this.returnToArray.shift();
          reqMethod = this.reqMethodArray.shift();
          // SEND THAT CALL
          this.doCall(whereTo, returnTo, reqMethod);
        }else{
          // UPDATE DEBUG QUEUE
        }
      }else{
        // UPDATE DEBUG QUEUE
      }
    },

    doCall : function(whereTo, returnTo){
      this.inCall = true;
      var http = this.createRequestObject();
      http.open('get', whereTo);
      // DO WE HAVE A FUNCTION TO CALL ONCE CALL IS COMPLETED?
      if(returnTo.length > 0){
        eval("http.onreadystatechange = " + returnTo);
      }
      // SEND CALL
      http.send(null);
    }
};

setInterval(requestQueue.callQueue, 100);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
setInterval(requestQueue.callQueue, 100);
```

Peels off the `callQueue` method from `requestQueue` and passes it to `setInterval`. Consequently `callQueue` has no reference to `requestQueue`; when it is called back, `this` will be set to `window` not `requestQueue` so the attempt to evaluate `this.callToArray.length` will cause an error.

`this` in JavaScript does not work in the way you would expect from any other language. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544735/js-object-this-method-breaks-via-jquery#1544893) for an explanation. If you only have one `requestQueue` instance you can just reference that instead of using `this`, otherwise you'll need to look into function binding or a closure.

Incidentally I'd not recommend UA-string-sniffing for detecting the right XHR object to use. Try feature-sniffing instead:

```
var r= window.XMLHttpRequest? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
```

(this would also use native XMLHttp on IE7+ where enabled, potentially avoiding an ActiveX prompt.)