# Can't access public variable in public method?

Tags: javascript, public-method

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JS Object this.method() breaks via jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544735/js-object-this-method-breaks-via-jquery)

Hello,

I'm playing around with creating classes in javascript but I don't think I really understand everything.

Here is some (simplified) code I wrote (the .bind() comes from jQuery 1.4.1):

```
function MyClass(size)
{
    this.myList = new Array(size);
    for (var i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        this.myList[i] = "Test " + i;
    }
}

MyClass.prototype.InitCells = function()
{
    $('#grid tbody tr td').bind('click', this.GetValue);
}

MyClass.prototype.GetValue = function()
{
    alert(this.myList[1]);
}
```

Then I do this in my HTML-file:

```
var test = new MyClass(10);
test.InitCells();
```

Then, when I click on one of the `<td>`'s, I get this error: 'this.myList is null or not an object'

What do I need to do to access myList in the GetValue method?

Comment: Seems like this question gets asked *every day* - the short answer is, you're misunderstanding how functions and the context object (`this`) work in JavaScript. For a longer answer, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544735/js-object-this-method-breaks-via-jquery
(picked at random).