# bold, header effects in alert()?

Tags: javascript, alert

in javascript, how to make alert bold n use h1 to h5 headers? Is this possible or simply plain alert is option?

how to include bold and h1 to this alert?

```
function onlooad()
{
    alert("wssup??");

}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can not use HTML in alert(). For that you need to use window.open() or some custom code like this:
http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog

Comment: Hi is jquery on top of javascript, i know little javascript, is it worth learning jquery?? Is it easy to use and faster in execution?

Comment: @abhilash M You might want to start here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2628672/what-every-javascript-programmer-should-know

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, this is impossible.

Answer (score 2):

You can use custom elements that act like alert boxes. Check this one out

**[jQuery Impromptu](http://trentrichardson.com/Impromptu/)**

Answer (score 1):

Javascript alert is limited in terms of formatting because it does not recognise HTML markup. If this is important, consider an in-page alternative. A quick web search turned up the following:

http://www.jondavis.net/codeprojects/jqalert/

Comment: spender what can be a solution to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9347654/combo-box-is-getting-vanished-when-an-alert-is-coming)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but in JavaScript, you can only use plaintext alerts. Now, you can use \n for a newline, by the way, but the alert() function only allows plaintext. Again, sorry.