# JavaScript object not working

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I am facing a problem with JavaScript objects. I have some text on a page which should converts into textfield when clicked. The problem is that when I click the text the console displays the error message

> "textNode not defined or null and tn is not defined".

Please help, I want to solve this problem in a way so that I don't have to move the JavaScript code to any other location from head tag.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Span to Text Box - Demo - DOM</title>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function preload()
{
if(!tn) var tn=new Object();
tn.variables=
{
textboxNode: document.getElementById('textbox'),
textNode: document.getElementById('text'),
textValue: textNode.firstChild.nodeValue,
doneButton: document.getElementById('done')
};
}

function change()
{
tn.variables.textboxNode.setAttribute('value', textValue);
tn.variables.textNode.style.display = 'none';
tn.variables.textboxNode.setAttribute('type','text');
tn.variables.doneButton.setAttribute('type','button');
}
function changeBack()
{
tn.variables.textNode.firstChild.nodeValue = textboxNode.value;
tn.variables.textNode.style.display = 'block';
tn.variables.textboxNode.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
tn.variables.doneButton.setAttribute('type','hidden');
}
</script>
</head>

<body onload= "preload()">
<p id="text" onClick="change()">Click me!</p>
<form onSubmit="return false;">
  <input type="hidden" id="textbox" />
  <input type="hidden" id="done" onClick="changeBack()" value="Done" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: WHAT SHOULD EVERY JAVA-SCRIPT PROGRAMMER KNOW? I want to share this most useful post with all my Freinds here. Here is the Link: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2628672/1067051

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object `tn` is local to the `preload` function.

Define it as global variable instead:

```
var tn = new Object();
function preload()
{
    tn.variables=
    {
        //....
    }
}
```

Also, you can't get other property value when you just define the object.

Change `textValue` to be a function instead:

```
tn.variables =
{
    textboxNode: document.getElementById('textbox'),
    textNode: document.getElementById('text'),
    textValue: function() {
        return this.textNode.firstChild.nodeValue;
    }, 
    doneButton: document.getElementById('done')
};
```

Then invoke it as function as well, for example:

```
tn.variables.textboxNode.setAttribute('value', tn.variables.textValue());
```

Answer (score 1):

i think your tn variable is not correctly set in a global scope. Try to modify the top of your javascript like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
var tn = null;
function preload()
{
   if(!tn) 
   {
      tn=new Object();
   }
   tn.variables=
   {
     textboxNode: document.getElementById('textbox'),
     textNode: document.getElementById('text'),
     textValue: textNode.firstChild.nodeValue,
     doneButton: document.getElementById('done')
   };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

to begin with, define tn globally - outside the scope of preload

Comment: no probs.. best of luck with the software.. have you tried the Javascript debugger in the Safari / Chrome Developer Tools? Or Firebug on Firefox? Useful stuff..