# how to run an instance of a class through out the application

Tags: c#

I know the title might not be clear and I apologize about that. 
so I have 2 forms in visual studio and in the first form user logs in to the system and the second form is where everything else happens.

I have called a class called `info` in the first form, and the class is responsible to gather user info and check for login etc. when a user logs into the system, the class takes the user ID and stores it into a private string. and from there the program goes into the second form.

now here is my question, how can I make this class global so I can access the stored userID from the second form? can I just create another instance of the class (`info myinfo = new info()`) ?

PS I am new to object oriented concept so Please user easy terms.

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C#". That's what tags are for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Personally, I would vote against globals. Instead, I usually do it the following way:

In the code that calls form 1, fetch the parameter from the form through a property. Pass it then to the second form through a parameter on the second form.

E.g.:

```
void Main()
{
    var form1 = new Form1();
    form1.ShowDialog();

    var info = form1.GetInfo();

    var form2 = new Form2();
    form2.SetInfo( info );
    form2.ShowDialog();
}
```

If you really insist on having a global class, please look at the [Singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern), as [wsanville pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8368464/107625). Basically it would roughly look like:

```
public sealed class Info
{
    private static Info _instance;
    private static readonly object _lock = new object();

    // Private to disallow instantiation.
    private Info()
    {
    }

    public static Info Instance
    {
        get
        {
            lock (_lock)
            {
                if (_instance==null)
                {
                    _instance = new Info();
                }
                return _instance;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: could you give me an example on how to do that?

Comment: thanks, thats a good solution but is there a way to have this class as global (as you can in PHP) and access it from all the forms?

Comment: @AhouraGhotbi Added this one, too.

Comment: The first answer is nice and testable. The singleton, not so much.

Comment: @AhouraGhotbi Thanks for answering my question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8286054/1067051 (PHP url functions and subdomains) accept some appreciation(votes) from me :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) to access one instance of your class throughout your application.  For an implementation in C#, see [Jon Skeet's article](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/singleton.html) on the subject.