# PHP automatically renaming downloaded files

Tags: php

I am new to PHP. I have a software downloads website. What I want is to 
automatically add "-mysite.com" with every download filename. So that the actual 
filename remain the same i.e "somesoftware.exe" but whenever someone download it, it should 
be automatically renamed and downloaded with the filename "somesoftware-
mysitename.com.exe" to their computer. Here is the code for download link div on my site.

```
    <!--===========================Download Div===============================-->

     <div id="downlink-container">
     <a href="http://www.mysitename.com/downloads/jetaudio16.0.0.435-mysitename.com.exe" id="downloadlink" style="visibility:visible">
      Download Jet Audio
     </a>
     </div>

     <!--===========================Download Div====================================-->
```

Can I use PHP to automatically add "-mysitename.com" with the downloaded file name 
"somesoftware.exe" so that the actual filename on server folder remain the same(i.e. 
somesoftware.exe) but whenever someone download it, it automatically become "somesoftware-
mysitename.com.exe". I tried using PHP variables for this but I can't get it done. Please 
Help!

Comment: show your current code please

Comment: RTM - http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: Please stop doing indirectly the advertising for your site in each of your questions.

Comment: @GG. I have replaced the words with mysitename. ok :-)

Comment: @GG. kindly undo the negative vote to my question if you like.

Comment: @capricorn It is not me, sorry. :(

Comment: WHAT SHOULD EVERY JAVA-SCRIPT PROGRAMMER KNOW? I want to share this most useful post with all my Freinds here. Here is the Link: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2628672/1067051

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set the following header:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="downloaded.pdf"');
```

Where `downloaded.pdf` is your filename. Its just a matter of getting the extention and adding "- thenoblesite.com" to the original name.

Answer (score 1):

Once user starts downloading a file, it's over - you have no control over it, no PHP, no anything. So the idea is to either rename the source file (which you don't want) or to actually stream the file using a different name. See it [here](http://www.webmasterworld.com/php/3333658.htm).

Comment: I want to share a useful link here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194812/list-of-freely-available-programming-books