# What are some things to keep in mind while working on the speed of a Phonegap app?

Tags: cordova

Will using jQuery or Zepto make a difference (if they are present locally and not pulled from a server)?

Will using a lot of images make it slow?

Will using a lot of CSS3 and HTML5 make it slow?

Will using a lot of javascript animation make it slow?

Should I build a multi-page application or a single page application?

Assumption: There is no server interaction.

Comment: I suspect that they are pretty much the same you would expect from Web app - minimize the amount of requests, paints, layout events, DOM interactions etc. PhoneGap, it seems to me, would have a lesser impact.

Comment: I'm sorry I do not understand paints, layout events, DOM interactions.

Comment: Well, then, you have bigger problems to worry about than PhoneGap performance. I suggest you read up on those, and Web application development practices in general.

Comment: Well that just adds to my problems doesn't it? From what you've told me I am guessing the answer to my question is - You "suspect" the things that affect the performance of a phonegap app are identical to the ones that affect a webapp or are you sure? Because if I am correct a webapp needs a server and a Phonegap app doesn't.

Comment: The general approach to development is similar, or at least based on the same principles. Server performance is only 1 part of the overall picture. The way you write your JavaScript, CSS and HTML, deliver your scripts, css files, images and fonts have as much if not more impact. I say "suspect" because I don't have the numbers. But before you go and try to optimize PhoneGap - there is so much more to do on your app, before you even get to the packaging process.

For example - memory leaks - these won't be immediately noticeable, but will become a big problem with prolonged use.

Comment: Now thank you for that. That adds a little clearer picture, I can search memory leaks and probably work on that. Could you please compile these thoughts and put it into an answer? I would be very grateful. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Putting that into an answer would be both very presumptions and very superfluous on my part. The list of required knowledge has been compiled on this very site hundreds of times.

Comment system, however, doesn't allow me to put links properly, so it'll have to be an answer with links to relevant answers. I suggest you to read through these (despite some of them being tangential to your needs).

SO threads:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194812/list-of-freely-available-programming-books/392926#392926
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11246/best-resources-to-learn-javascript
3. [What should every JavaScript programmer know?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2628672/what-should-every-javascript-programmer-know)

My own suggestions:

http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920025245.do (can be found in pieces for free I would think)

Other than these - do a SO search, it should serve you fine.