# Hover over element animate next element - How to remove inline JS

Tags: javascript, html, inline-code, rollover-effect

I'm relatively new to JavaScript, but I'm trying to find a more efficient method for calling a rollover function without using inline events within the HTML. Below is the method I'm currently using:

HTML

```
        <div id="work_square">
        <img onmouseover="rolloverIn('rollover_1');" onmouseout="rolloverOut('rollover_1');" src="images/frugal_image.png" width="100%"/>
        <div onmouseover="rolloverIn('rollover_1');" onmouseout="rolloverOut('rollover_1');" id="rollover_1" class="rollovers">
            <div id="rollover_text">
                <h2>ROLLOVER 1 TITLE</h2>
                <p>This is rollover 1.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="work_square">
        <img onmouseover="rolloverIn('rollover_2');" onmouseout="rolloverOut('rollover_2');" src="images/exhibiton_image.jpg" width="100%"/>
        <div onmouseover="rolloverIn('rollover_2');" onmouseout="rolloverOut('rollover_2');" id="rollover_2" class="rollovers">
            <div id="rollover_text">
                <h2>ROLLOVER 2 TITLE</h2>
                <p>This is rollover 2.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

JS

```
<script>
function rolloverIn(el){
    var elem = document.getElementById(el);
    elem.style.opacity = 1;
    elem.style.transform = "scale(1)";
}
function rolloverOut(el){
    var elem = document.getElementById(el);
    elem.style.opacity = 0;
    elem.style.transform = "scale(0)";
}
```

Basically I'm calling a function to apply a CSS transform and opacity alteration for a rollover placed over each work_square when either the image or rollover is moused over, and then to remove the alterations on mouse out.

This method **works**, but it's my understanding that inline coding is bad practice. Could someone point me in the right direction towards a more efficient method?

Thanks.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener

Comment: IDs ARE UNIQUE FOR GOD'S SAKE

Comment: You can user jquery for removing inline function call
$('#rollover_1').mouseover(function() {

  //do something here on mouse hover
 });
 $('#rollover_1').mouseout(function() {
  //do something here on mouse out.
 });

Comment: Delete your question and start reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2628672/what-should-every-javascript-programmer-know/2629004#2629004, http://tutorialzine.com/2014/04/10-mistakes-javascript-beginners-make/, http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/training-courses/javascript-fundamentals-for-absolute-beginners etc.

Comment: Do you not like CSS, for some reason? JavaScript seems entirely unnecessary here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sup>Sorry to ruin your dream of using JS but</sup>  
**this is all doable in pure CSS**:

```css
.work_square{ position:relative; }
.work_square > img{ width:100%; }

.work_square .rollovers{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  opacity:0;
  transform: scale(0);
  transition: 0.6s;
}
.work_square:hover .rollovers{
  transform: scale(1);
  opacity:1;
}
```

```html
    <div class="work_square">
      <img src="//placehold.it/800x300/cf5" />
      <div class="rollovers">
        <div class="rollover_text">
          <h2>ROLLOVER 1 TITLE</h2>
          <p>This is rollover 1.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="work_square">
      <img src="//placehold.it/800x300/f5f" />
      <div class="rollovers">
        <div class="rollover_text">
          <h2>ROLLOVER 2 TITLE</h2>
          <p>This is rollover 2.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Note that **I've removed all unnecessary ID** (hey, you cannot use duplicate ID's in a *valid* HTML document).
Use your container class `.work_square` and use the CSS `:hover` on it to add that listener, than simply add the desired class of the children element to target:

```
.work_square:hover .rollovers{
```

Comment: I've added the '*valid*' qualifier to your statement. Obviously edit it out if you feel I've introduced an error, but duplicate `id`s *can* be used, even if they shouldn't be.

Comment: Thanks a lot, cleaned it all up now and it works perfectly. You may have crushed my JS dream, but at least this is a step towards better practice :)

Comment: Thanks @David. It's more accurate.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, **do not ever use the same ID for multiple elements**, IDs are unique. What you want here are classes, so your HTML code should be changed to something like this:

```
<div class="work_square">
    <img class="rollover" src="images/frugal_image.png" width="100%"/>
    <div class="rollover">
        <div class="rollover_text">
            <h2>ROLLOVER 1 TITLE</h2>
            <p>This is rollover 1.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="work_square">
    <img class="rollover" src="images/exhibiton_image.jpg" width="100%"/>
    <div class="rollover">
        <div class="rollover_text">
            <h2>ROLLOVER 2 TITLE</h2>
            <p>This is rollover 2.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, if you want to use pure JavaScript, without inline code, you can easily use the `rollover`  class to select all the elements and bind the `mouseover` and `mouseout` events to your functions. Here is the correct code:

```
function rolloverIn(e){
    this.style.opacity = 1;
    this.style.transform = "scale(1)";
}

function rolloverOut(e){
    this.style.opacity = 0;
    this.style.transform = "scale(0)";
}

var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('rollover');
for (var i=0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].addEventListener('mouseover', rolloverIn);
    elements[i].addEventListener('mouseout', rolloverOut);
}
```