# TypeError: this is not a Date object

Tags: javascript

Any idea why this does not work in Chrome?
`var foo = (new Date).getDate;

     foo();`
I get a TypeError: this is not a Date object. However `(new Date).getDate()` works

Comment: If you've stumbled across this question and you're using a `Proxy`, read this: http://2ality.com/2016/11/proxying-builtins.html#wrapping-instances-of-built-in-constructors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript, the `this` context is **not** bound to each method of an object. Rather, it is determined at run-time by the way you *call* that method [Check this answer for more about the binding behaviour.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1544893/1321716).

In your code, `foo` receives the `getDate` property of `new Date`, which it receives from the `Date.prototype` through the prototype chain. Thus, your code is really equivalent to:

```
var foo = Date.prototype.getDate;
foo();
```

(Test this yourself: verify in your console that `(new Date).getDate === Date.prototype.getDate` is indeed `true`.)

Now, it should be clear that there's no actual `this` context for that call. You could set it up beforehand by manually `bind`ing the function to an object. (Note: [older browsers need a shiv](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Compatibility) for `Function.prototype.bind`.)

```
var foo = Date.prototype.getDate.bind(new Date);
foo();
```

Alternatively, set up the proper `this` context when you `call`/`apply` the function.

```
var foo = Date.prototype.getDate;
foo.call(new Date);
```

Answer (score 4):

The function is not properly bound in your example. The "this" object for that foo call isn't the original date object.

One way to make the logic work is to bind the function:

```
var x = new Date();
var foo = x.getDate.bind(x);
foo();
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `this`, when you call the function, isn't a date but the global context (`window`).

You may do this :

```
foo.call(new Date());
```

Or, if you want to be able to use the function from anywhere and still use the original date, you may use

```
var date = new Date();
var foo = function() { return date.getDate() }; // returns always the same date
```

or

```
var foo = function() { return (new Date()).getDate() }; // returns the current date
```

If there weren't IE8, you could also use [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) :

```
var foo = date.bind(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is either

```
var date = new Date;
var foo = date.getDate.bind(Date)
foo()
```

or

```
var date = new Date;
var foo = date.getDate;
foo.call(date);
```

When you call `foo` as you did, it won't have a reference to a date object, which is why it throws an error.

Answer (score 0):

Because `foo` in your code is just a function which is not bind with any object. It requires some other info from `Date` object in order to be called. You can do this:

```
var date = new Date()
var foo = date.getDate
foo.call(date)
```