# Uncaught TypeError: this is not a Date object when adding a function to Date prototype

Tags: javascript, prototype

I have a problem with this code in google chrome and firefox.  `this.setUTCDate(1);` throws Uncaught TypeError: this is not a Date object. How can I fix it?

I've looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17899598/typeerror-this-is-not-a-date-object) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544735/js-object-this-method-breaks-via-jquery/1544893#1544893), but I didn't find anything to solve my problem.

```
Date.prototype.setUTCDateOnly = function(date) {
    var tmp = new Date(date);
    this.setUTCDate(1);
};
```

I am calling it in this way:

```
var date = Date.prototype.setUTCDateOnly(item.date);
```

Comment: How are you calling `setUTCDateOnly()`?

Comment: @RocketHazmat in this way : var date = Date.prototype.setUTCDateOnly(item.date);

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: this is not a Date object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17899598/typeerror-this-is-not-a-date-object)

Comment: Well there you go. It indeed is not a Date object. Why are you calling it that way?

Comment: I used a library for calendar. it's developer does not answer any questions. so I started to edit the code. the above codes works already before I upgraded my browser

Comment: Now I need your helps to solve the problem

Comment: @Пуя You have not explained what it is that you want the function to actually do.

Comment: It has another codes after that line. I want to set only the year, month, date parts (keep existing time)

Comment: Thanks for the down votes :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you call your method like this

```
Date.prototype.setUTCDateOnly(item.date);
```

then the `this` value will be `Date.prototype`.

In ES5, [`Date.prototype`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.5) was a Date object:

> The Date prototype object is itself a Date object (its [[Class]] is `"Date"`) whose [[PrimitiveValue]] is **NaN**.

Therefore, you could call `setUTCDate` on it. The `NaN` was just transformed into a `+0` by [ToInteger](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.4) inside [MakeDay](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.12).

However, this changed in ES6, now [`Date.prototype`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-properties-of-the-date-prototype-object) is defined as

> The Date prototype object is itself an ordinary object. It is not a
>   Date instance and does not have a [[DateValue]] [internal slot](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots).

Therefore, attempting to call `setUTCDate` on it throws.

Comment: Thanks, Because I didn't know that the new google chrome changed the ECMA script engine to 6

Comment: @Пуя It's more like a gradual transition. New browser versions are becoming closer to the ES6 spec.

Answer (score 3):

Methods added to the `.prototype` of a constructor are meant to operate on instances created from that constructor. Instead, you're operating on the `.prototype` object itself.

Why? Because the value of `this` in your case is set by looking to the left hand side of the `.` operator. In other words, the object on which the method is called becomes the value of `this` in the method.

That's not the only way `this` can be set, but it is the default, implicit behavior when invoking methods.

So what you need to do is create a Date object like you normally would, then call your method on that object to have it operate on that object.

```
var mydate = new Date();
mydate.setUTCDateOnly(item.date);
```